# Find first and second occurrence with condition

Tags: excel, lookup

I have the table below...

```
Key   Result
1       T
2       G
2       T
3       T
3       T
4       G
4       T
4       T
5       G
5       T
5       T
```

I need to perform a lookup which will locate the `Key` and check whether that `Key` has T or G for the `Result`, and give 1 if it does and 0 if not.

So for the above table, my two formulas should return the following...

```
Key   T   G
1     1   0
2     1   1
3     1   0
4     1   1
5     1   1
```

Obviously `VLOOKUP` won't work because it only finds the first occurrence, so I tried using `INDEX-MATCH`

```
=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A2,$A:$A,0),1)
```

The above formula returns the `Result` for each `Key`, but how would I modify it to return 1 if the result is `T` and 0 otherwise?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,F1)>0,"1","0")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**There are many ways to achieve this, here's an example for two of them:**

***Assumes lookup table is in `Sheet2!A:C`***

*String Concatenation in `MATCH()`*

`=--ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2&"T",$A:$A&$B:$B,0))`

or
`=--ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2&B$1,Sheet1!$A:$A&Sheet1!$B:$B,0))`

*Using `COUNTIF()`*

`=--(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,"T")>0)`

or
`=--(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,B$1)>0)`

You can use `IF([],1,0)` instead of the `--`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am a little confused about this formula. It doesn't seem like it is looking for "T" or "G", so how does it work? I need the formula to find every occurrence of the key and return 1 if any of the results for that key are "T", otherwise 0. And a second formula to do the same for "G"

Comment: Sorry I was looking at your example table and referencing the column headers... I'll edit in static formula.

Comment: I ended up doing it slightly differently, but your implementation helped me figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Key` is in A1, please construct the headers for your output (say with `Key` in D1) then in E2:

```
=1*(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D2,$B:$B,E$1)>0)
```

copied across and down to F6.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of [array (CTRL + Enter) formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) ?

Assuming you only want to know if there is a G *result* for one key, this is what I would suggest you:

1. Do a multiplication of the comparaison between your key and your value.

   `=($A$2:$A$12=KEY)*($B$2:$B$12=RESULT)`
   (Where KEY and RESULT are the cells for your actual values (1,2,3... for the KEY, T or G for the RESULT) then press CTRL+ENTER. If you use the [Evaluate Formula button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7), you'll understand how this is working quite easily.
2. If you simply do a `MAX` on this array, then you'll end up with a 1 if your request (i.e. if you have both your KEY and your RESULT in your "table"), otherwise, you'll have a 0.

Using this approach, but changing the `MAX` by a `SUM` will give you the number of occurrences where your criteria are matched.

*Remember to always press CTRL+ENTER when you finish editing your array formula!*

Final formula `=MAX(($A$2:$A$12=$A19)*($B$2:$B$12=B$18))`